# Understanding how to find roots of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(N)$

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

I am having difficulties understanding why the roots of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ algebra are $\alpha_{ij}=e_i-e_j$. This is (roughly) what my professor said:

> We define the ladder operators in $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ as the matrices $E_{ij}$ such that they have a $1$ in the $(i,j)$-position and $i\neq j$. Given $H=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N)$ we have $[H,E_{ij}]=(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)E_{ij}$. Then, if we take the elements of Cartan subalgebra to be $E_{ii}-\frac1N I_N$ (where $I_N$ is the identity matrix) we get that the roots are
> $$\alpha_{ij}=e_i-e_j$$
> where $i\neq j$ so there are $N(N-1)$ of them.

I understand $[H,E_{ij}]=(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)E_{ij}$ ([example on WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=%7B%7Bx%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Cy%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cz%7D%7D%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D-%7B%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D%7B%7Bx%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Cy%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cz%7D%7D)) but I don't get how
$$[E_{kk}-\frac1N I_N,E_{ij}]$$
would give those roots.

P. S. I know that in general $[H_i,E_\alpha]=\alpha_i\,E_\alpha$.

Comment: That presentation is not very good. First of all, roots live on the complexified Lie algebra which here is $sl_N(\mathbb C)$ (note how basically all matrices mentioned here are not even in $su_N$). Then, those elements *span* a Cartan subalgebra, but they are a poor choice of basis for it (and the CSA can be described much better as the traceless diagonal matrices). And then, there are actually $N(N-1)$ roots in the root system (count the pairs with $i\neq j$). There are $N-1$ *simple roots*, e.g. one can choose the ones with $j=i+1$, but that's a different matter.

Comment: That $N-1$ is a typo, I meant as you said

Comment: Well good. Just forget that strange basis of the Cartan. The relation $[H, E_{ij}]=(\lambda_i - \lambda_j) E_{ij}$ (for any diagonal $H$, in particular for all elements of our Cartan subalgebra) says that the root with root space $E_{ij}$ is the $\alpha_{ij}$ as described. If that is not clear, then what is your definition of a root and what kind of expression would make sense for one?

Comment: About the complexification, by $su(N)$ I mean complexified $su(N)$

Comment: The thing that bugs me is that normally we have $[H_i, E_\alpha]=\alpha_i E_\alpha$ and the root Is obtained by applying every element of CSA, while in this case the indices are of $E$ not $H$. I don't know if I made myself clear

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand it this way: ($I_N$ commutes with $E_{ij}$)
$$[E_{kk},E_{ij}]=([E_{kk}]_{ii}-[E_{kk}]_{jj})E_{ij}=(\delta_{ki}-\delta_{kj})E_{ij}$$
since $E_{kk}$ has a $1$ in $kk$ entry, we have $[E_{kk}]_{ii}=\delta_{ki}$.

Then, in analogy with $[H_i,E_\alpha]=\alpha_i\,E_\alpha$ we found that $\delta_{ki}-\delta_{kj}$ is the $k$-th entry of the root $\alpha_{ij}$ associated with $E_{ij}$. Therefore

$$[\alpha_{ij}]_k=\begin{cases}0&k\neq i,j\\1&k=i\\-1&k=j\end{cases}$$
so $\alpha_{ij}=(0,\dots,0,1,\dots,-1,0,\dots,0)$ where the $1$ and $-1$ are in $i$-th entry and $j$-th entry respectively. This is equivalent to say $\alpha_{ij}=e_i-e_j$

Comment: That looks plausible. Notations differ wildly; I am used to viewing a root as a linear map from a Cartan subalgebra to the ground field. Here, I think we agree that if viewed that way, the root $\alpha_{ij}$ would map the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$ to $\lambda_i - \lambda_j$.

Comment: Alright, thank you. As a last thing, I would like to understand why you say that $E_{ii}-1/N I_N$ is a strange basis for the CSA even if they are traceless diagonal matrices

Comment: Well sure, any $N-1$ linearly independent traceless diagonal matrices are a vector space basis of that CSA, and so far each is a as good as any other. But when using the Lie structure, and the roots tructure, often one would want a basis which modulo some identifications consists of coroots (often called $H_\alpha$). E.g. here a "good" choice of basis would be $H_1 =E_{11}-E_{22}, H_2 = E_{22}-E_{33}, ..., H_{N-1}= E_{N-1,N-1} - E_{NN}$.